# Suggest the regex for pattern

Tags: regex

I have the script here with multiple "(" and ")":

```
#if( a == b && a == c ) Content 1 #elseif( ( a == b ) && (a != c) ) Content 2 #elseif( (a != b) && (a != c) ) Content 3 #end
```

And I want to using java.util.regex.Pattern to get the condition of this script. And the result I want:

- ## if( a == b && a == c )
- ## elseif( ( a == b ) && (a != c) )
- ## elseif( (a != b) && (a != c) )

I have using:
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(#if|#elseif)+(.*?)((([^)]){1,}))");
But the result is not expected. Please help me the regex here.
Thank you so much.

Comment: If the `if` or `elseif` **statements** are limited to one line, then may be you can try something like [THIS](https://regex101.com/r/jXDq29/2).

Comment: @Gurman Thank you, but I run on Java it working not expected. I using this tool https://www.regextester.com/ and run on my app.

Comment: @Gurman my script is:
#if( a == b && a == c )  Current cycle of the {plan} is about to expire, and you credit card will be charged #elseif( ( a == b ) && (a != c) ) The {plan} is about to expire. please purchase another plan to use our services #elseif( (a != b) && (a != c) ) The {plan} will get expired in 1 min please purchase a plan to use our Smart services #end .

not break line. Thanks

Comment: What script? In regextester, it works as shown [HERE](https://www.regextester.com/?fam=99273).

Comment: @Gurman Yes, with if or elseif statements are limited to one line, your regex work ok, but with my script as on my question edited, it work not expected, please help me again. Thank you.

Comment: Ohh I did not see the updated question. My bad.

Comment: Yes, I edited at a moment, I have test on this https://www.regextester.com/?fam=99274, please help me review. Thanks.

Comment: Try this one `(?:if|elseif)\s*\(([^()]+\)|.*?\)(?:\s*\))+)`?

Comment: Yes it working perfect @Gurman. Thank you so much.

Comment: Ok. posting it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Regex:

`(?:if|elseif)\s*\((?:[^()]+\)|.*?\)(?:\s*\))+)`

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/d0l0xw/1)

**Explanation:**

- `(?:if|elseif)` - matches `if` or `elseif`
- `\s*` - matches 0+ occurrences of a whitespace character
- `[^()]+\)` - matches 1+ occurrences of any character which is neither `(` nor `)`. This is then followed by a matching `)`
- `|` - OR
- `.*?\)(?:\s*\))+` - handles the case with nested parenthesis `()`

Updated expression:

[`#(?:if|elseif)\s*\((?:[^()]*\)|[^#]+\))`](https://regex101.com/r/d0l0xw/11)

Comment: Hi @Gurman
With the same regex above, in this case, it not working https://regex101.com/r/d0l0xw/6
the regextester: #if( {plan:tag} == "(Good]" )Good #elseif ( !({plan:tag} == "[Bad)") ) not expected.
Please help me again. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, I see, so I think maybe we cannot using regex for this case, do you think so :)

Comment: @BenJima You are correct. You can unselect it as the answer. I will get back to you if I come up with a better expression(maybe after work). I created a regex only for the examples you had mentioned in your question

Comment: Yes, thank you @Gurman I will try to find solutions while waiting for you :D

Comment: @BenJima I hope [THIS](https://regex101.com/r/d0l0xw/11) is what you wanted. Note: This will fail only if there is a `#` placed somewhere inside those if or elseif conditions.

Comment: Thank you so much, but I think this case is difficult so I'll follow this solution, I'll split this case.
So please help me suggest the expression for this string:
`"Good" and "(Good]" or "[Bad)".`
The result expected should be contains `"("` or `")"` as: `"(Good]"` , `"[Bad)"`
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Java doesn't support recursion, so you can't properly match balanced parenthesized groups. If you don't expect that the part after the if/elseif conditions will ever contain parentheses, you can use the following workaround:

```
(?m)^#(?:if|elseif).*? (?!.*[()])(.+)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I think your expression is working for PHP, I have changed to Javascript it not working https://regex101.com/r/d3Xior/2

Comment: You mentioned using "java.util.regex.Pattern" in your original question - are you not using Java? Java and Javascript are, of course, different, and so are the regex flavours they support.

Comment: I using Java for Android, and I always using Javascript expression to test pattern for this. Please suggest the expression for Java. Thanks.

Comment: This _is_ the Java expression for this. Instead of testing it on an incompatible flavour, why don't you try it in your actual application?

Comment: I have try on my app but it error:
"Regular expression '"(?m)^#(?:if|elseif)\\((\\((?1)\\)|.)*\\) (.+)"' is malformed: Unknown inline modifier less... (Ctrl+F1) "

Comment: and more this: "java.util.regex.Pattern or java.lang.String and do not fit the standard Java regular expression syntax."

Comment: As you see on my regex testing https://regex101.com/r/d3Xior/2, it warning "pattern error". Thanks

Comment: Ah sorry, apparently recursion is not supported by java.util.regex.Pattern. Let me update my answer.

Comment: With Gurman answered above "(?:if|elseif)\s*\(([^()]+\)|.*?\)(?:\s*\))+)?" and it working expected @jaytea. Thank you so much.